# Firebase ML Kit translation for Chinese language - Offline mode

Tags: firebase, google-mlkit

What API shall I use to detect the language for translation when I am in offline mode? I can translate the Chinese characters using google vision but it does not work with Firebase ML kit when I am in offline mode. Any idea or inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The on-device models in ML Kit only support latin character set. From the documentation on [Text Recognition](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition):

> With ML Kit's text recognition APIs can recognize text in **any Latin-based character set**.

If you want to detect other character sets, you'll have to be online to use the Cloud API, or find a different on-device model to use that supports other character sets.